# How to follow (or favourite) particular users?

Tags: feature-request

Is there a way to follow particular users?

The obvious answer is to look at their profile pages and check their recent activity. But what if there are a dozen (or more) users I want to follow? It'd be far more helpful whenever I sign in to find alerts indicating that one of my favourite users has posted a new question/answer/comment (an Alert Box in addition to the Inbox and the Notifications).

If there is no way to do this currently (I couldn't find anything), please consider adding these new features: ability to favourite select users; alerts for new activity from these users indicating the type of activity and the tag(s); ability to delete the alerts. Or, at least consider adding a section to the profile page where a user can keep a list of favourite users (and link directly to their profile pages).

Thanks.

Comment: Subscribe to their RSS feeds. Simple as that.

Comment: @RegDwighт: How do you do that? What link/part of their profile do you submit to your RSS reader?

Comment: Thanks @RegDwighт. I'm chuckling. Funny thing is I almost wrote "something like an RSS feed" in my post. Somehow I missed the tiny icon in the bottom R corner. Could have something to do with my smaller laptop screen and not scrolling lower than the questions and answers sections. :-) However, if the powers that be are looking to improve the site, I still think the specifics of the suggestions made in my post would be even better than subscribing to an RSS feed.

Comment: @Mitch - I clicked on the RSS "user feed" in the bottom R corner of a profile page. That took me to a page of the user's activity and a menu bar on the R gives options including subscribing to the feed by your computer's mail system and adding a bookmark. (I thought clicking on "Add Bookmark..." would link me to steps, but it's just a prompt for people to add a bookmark as they normally would). I've bookmarked your feed based on reading your comments in the main site. Do something new and I'll see if my set up works. :-)

Comment: @Mitch - Works! Just got updates for another user I'm following. A "(6)" appeared next to the folder name on my bookmarks bar indicating 6 new actions.

Comment: @user49891 if this is your accepted solution you could post that as an answer then

Comment: Done. But I think it'd be more appropriate to post the question and answer in the help section of the main site. @RegDwighт, how do I do that? I searched for a "help" tag but nothing came up.

Comment: @Mitch - It occurs to me that you could have been prompting details for my benefit.

Answer (score 4):

1. Scroll to the bottom of a profile page.
2. Click on the RSS "user feed" icon in the bottom R corner. That will take you to a page of the user's activity.
3. Scan down the menu bar on the R. Options for adding RSS feeds are found under "Action."
4. Click to subscribe to the feed using your computer's mail system.
   Or, add a bookmark as you would for other web pages. (I have added mine to a dedicated folder in my bookmarks bar. New activity alerts are indicated by number beside the filename. Scrolling down the contents of the folder I can see how that number is distributed for each user).

Comment: For what it's worth, this did not work for me on Chrome for OSX. I got a page of unformatted text – looks like a content type wasn't set correctly or something.

Comment: That's too bad. I'm using Safari (Lion OS). Not familiar with Chrome but I would hope some tweaking could fix things. Hopefully an experienced Chrome user can shed some light...